# how to split JMX metrics in folders, dropwizard?

Tags: jmx, dropwizard

`Dropwizard` piles up all the metrics from `MetricRegistry` into one folder, making it complicated to observe without using additional tools like Graphite.

[Plain list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eC9S.png)

How can i organize them to packages like in java.nio package?

Additionally i'd like to separate metrics i didn't set up explicitly:

- REST timer
- JDBI stats